# OCaml '_a is not allowed in programs?

Tags: ubuntu, compilation, makefile, ocaml

I'm working with OCaml on Ubuntu 12.04 and I'm trying to use the make function to compile it but it doesn't quite work.

Currently trying to compile the program EVA2H1 but it returns

```
ocamlc -w A -g -c error.mli
File "error.mli", line 54, characters 3-6:
Error: The type variable name '_a is now allowed in programs
make: *** [error.cmi] Error 2"
```

I googled this " '_a is not allowed in programs" and came across here http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/OCaml_Errors so I typed in

```
# let f = List.sort compare;;
val f : '_a list -> '_a list = <fun>
# f [2;1;3];;
- : int list = [1; 2; 3]
# f;;
- : int list -> int list = <fun>
```

but it still didn't fix the problem, can anyone help?

I'm using the code from this site http://www.lsv.ens-cachan.fr/Software/evatrans2/
and I downloaded EVA2H1 with the EVAtrans library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact is that type variables beginning with `'_` aren't allowed in OCaml programs. They are used by the compiler/interpreter to indicate monomorphic but as yet unspecified type variables. To make this be unambiguous, it's forbidden to use them when writing code.

If the source code you're working with actually has such type variables in it, most likely it was written for an earlier version of OCaml.

The example you saw on the net shows output from the compiler/interpreter, not user-written code. That's why it has `'_a list` in it.

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't realise the version would matter. I'll see if I can get my hands on an earlier version and try from there.

Comment: This is just an educated guess based on the fact that the EVA code looks like it's from quite a while ago, the fact that OCaml has changed a lot over the last 10 years, and the fact that these type ids really are not allowed by the current OCaml 4.01.0 system. Depending on what you want to do, using an old OCaml system might work for you. You could also try mechanically renaming the type variables of the source (somewhat risky I guess).

Comment: See [this discussion](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/ml-archives/caml-list/2003/05/761de56f95a2c49592900819416db0ab.fr.html) from 2003 about the precise problem in EVAlib's `error.ml`.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the couple of hacks that made the library fail to compile under post-2003 versions of OCaml. See the updated tarball [here](http://gallium.inria.fr/~scherer/tmp/EVAlib-3.12.tar).